# Why putting the backslash character ( \ ) between characters in commands still works normally in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I am using ubuntu. I accidentally found out `l\s \-la`  works same as  `ls -la` . I also verified this does not work in windows command prompt or powershell.

Why does this work and Why I didn't get any error on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **backslash** is an escape character in shell, which means it will preserve the literal value of the following character, unless it's an exception like **newline** or a special shell character.

So, **\s** is equivalent to **s**, because s is not a shell special character.